# Upload Xamarin application on google play ( Alpha) - Unoptimized APK

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play, publishing

Im trying to upload my app as an alpha release on google play and I'm getting this error:

[Imagem do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGF4N.png)

First I thought that using the "Generate one package (.apk) per selected ABI" whould solve the problem since the error says that I can manage multiple APKs, but it didnt (this screenshot is from one of the APKs generated when I distribute an archive by Ad-Hoc).

If its relevant information, I'm already using linking for SDK And User Assemblies, and my .APK size is 11.9MB on the console.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: check my blog here :https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/reducing-the-app-size-in-xamarin-deep-dive-7ddc9cb12688

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, this isn't an error, it's a warning. It's ok to ignore it.

Xamarin does not yet have support for the Android App Bundle format, but they are working on it. The [tracking bug is here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2727).

Comment: check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59656953/1855177

Answer (score 1):

**Check the following steps to create a release mode apk in visual studio**

1.Disable Debugging mode.

2.Uncheck shared runtime

3.Make sure Configuration mode is "Release".

4.Set linking to **SDK And User Assemblies**(which will reduce app size)