# This apk results in unused code and resources

Tags: xamarin, google-play

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and generated apk its size is 20 M when i'm trying to upload it on google play store i got this error message 
"This apk results in unused code and resources being sent to users", i enabled ProGaurd and Multi-Dex and Linking Sdk Assemblies only on release mode but still getting this error, can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: you may have made a mistake in reducing the size, please refer to this[Shrinking Your Android App Size](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/shrinking-android-app-size/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the App Bundles. For now you can ignore it. More informations in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56494765/9823528

Comment: They are enforcing this BS now.