# Can't publish Xamarin.Forms App's APK file on Google Play Store

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-play, apk, publish

I want to publish my **Xamarin.Forms App** to **Google Play** Store. But when I upload the **APK** it gives me warning and disables **roll-out** option. It says we need to use Android App Bundle (**.aab**) format so that **APK** can be optimized for size and resources.

Currently, **Visual Studio 2019** Archive option does not support the **Android App Bundle**. I have taken latest update of **Visual Studio 2019** but still above format is not supported.

I googled and found some link to do this from the command prompt by modifying some settings in the Project file. But the build returns errors after couple of minutes with `exit code 1`.
This is frustrating as I can't publish it to **Google Play** Store. I have already published the **iOS** version of **App**.

Any help here will be very much appreciated.

Comment: For now skip that warning and complete all other settings in app store for your app and comeback after finishing all those setup then you can roll-out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload Xamarin application on google play ( Alpha) - Unoptimized APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398847/upload-xamarin-application-on-google-play-alpha-unoptimized-apk)

Answer (score 0):

Me and my team are currently releasing to **Google Play** with no problems our app as **APK**.

The **App Boundle** is a nice way to release smaller applications by delivering just what the device that downloads your application needs. The **Xamarin Show** published recently a video on this topic, that could be of interest for you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IOZ0SUKZq4

---

Through the following images i show how we upload/publish our **APK**:

First, in the image below you see that **APKs** are still supported:

[image]

**APK** uploads correctly:

[image]

Then we are able to save and review the **APK**:

[image]

**APK** is uploaded with ***warning***:

[image]

The warning states:

[image]

For now we just ignore the warning and go on to roll out:

[image]

---

In case that after following those steps your ***Start Rollout*** option is not yet enabled, it might be the case that you still have some other **Listing Sections** for your **Application**. After you introduce all the information required by **Google**, the ***Start Rollout*** option must be available.

Comment: Hi, I was able to publish APK and thanks for your answer. Once I completed other sections and came back to Manage release then roll out option was enabled for me.

Comment: Hi @Gokuldas, i updated my answer to include the information you provided. If you consider that the contents of this Answer include the solution for your problem, then YOU have to mark it as Answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Gokuldas, note that at the top of the answer on the left, just below the up/down arrows you can see a grayed check symbol (only the one who created the question can see this icon!). To accept the answer you have to click there. To vote up/down an answer you click up or down on the up/down arrows. :)